# Rasterio: Use case for src.meta vs. src.profile when reading and writing rasters?

Tags: python, raster, mapbox, metadata, rasterio

When I read a raster in with rasterio (version 0.36.0) in Python, I can call up the metadata in two ways:

```
src = rasterio.open(my_raster)

src.profile

{'affine': Affine(1.0, 0.0, 401900.0, 0.0, -1.0, 7620200.0),
'count': 1,  'crs': CRS({'init': 'epsg:32606'}),  'driver': 'GTiff',
'dtype': 'float32',  'height': 11100,  'interleave': 'band',
'nodata': -9999.0,  'tiled': False,
'transform': (401900.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7620200.0, 0.0, -1.0),  'width': 13750}

src.meta

{'affine': Affine(1.0, 0.0, 401900.0, 0.0, -1.0, 7620200.0),
'count': 1,  'crs': CRS({'init': 'epsg:32606'}),  'driver': 'GTiff',
'dtype': 'float32',  'height': 11100,  'nodata': -9999.0,
'transform': (401900.0, 1.0, 0.0, 7620200.0, 0.0, -1.0),  'width': 13750}
```

The results are quite similar, but profile stores a little more information such as the tiling and interleave information. Which of these methods is a better practice for retrieving metadata? Are there examples where one is better than the other? Both 'meta' and 'profile' seem to work fine right now for writing the single band float32 raster I am working with.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The [`meta` property](http://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio._base.html?highlight=meta#rasterio._base.DatasetBase.meta) contains the basic raster metadata. The [`profile` property](http://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio._base.html?highlight=meta#rasterio._base.DatasetBase.profile) is a super set of `meta` which includes dataset creation options (i.e inc. tiling, block size, compression etc...).

You would use `src.profile` when you want to ensure you create an exact (empty) clone of an existing dataset.  And it is especially useful when you are reading in block windows from a very large raster, then writing the chunks back out to your new raster as it is a lot faster if the input and output rasters have the same block layout.

Further info:

- https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/pull/406#issuecomment-119010268
- https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio/issues/405

Comment: thanks for the answer. I followed up on the links. I think I will make a habit of using the profile option from here on out.