# Increased raster file size after clipping and uploading to GCS

Tags: rasterio, compression, file-size, map-overviews

I have written a script that access cogs on GCS (google cloud storage), clip it with several vectors I have, and then uploading it back to GCS.
I thought that the clipped image size should be the same/lower size after the clipping, however, I was surprise to see that even though the images are the same , It is now heavier.

for example. an image with size of 635.6 MB before the clipping, is 951 MB after.

Details about how I preformed the clipping:

1. read data from GCS - vector data and each time one raster
2. used rastio.mask.mask to mask the raster
3. saved the raster locally with rasterio, using the following parameters:

```
    with rasterio.open(savedir /'clipped.tif', 
                                   'w',
                                   driver='cog',
                                   height=img_arr.shape[1],
                                   width=img_arr.shape[2],
                                   count=25,
                                   dtype=img_arr.dtype,
                                   crs=crs_img,
                                   nodata=None, 
                                   transform=transf) as dst:

            for n in np.arange(0,number_of_bands):
                  dst.write(img[n,:,:],int(n+1))
                  dst.set_band_description(int(n+1), band_names[n])
```

4. uploaded to GCS

**the pixels of the two images (before and after) have the same values** (where they are not clipped) . I thought maybe it has to do with **image dtype/ saving as cog,** but I need clue for understanding why I have this difference.

I have seen [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/164374/clipping-raster-image-increases-file-size) but I am not sure if it's the same on rasterio and if my solution will be just to add to "compress='lzw'" parameter, and how will it affect the images.

My goal is to understand what could increase the size of my GeoTIFFs

**EDIT: Overviews**
based on  user2856 comment, [I have checked the overviews](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/topics/overviews.html) and I found out that the clipped image is saved with overview:

```
metadata = src.meta

# Get overviews
overviews = src.overviews(1)  # the first band

# Print the metadata and overviews
print(metadata)
print(overviews)

>>>
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 3340, 'height': 3342, 'count': 22, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(removed)}
[]

...
metadata = clipped.meta

# Get overviews
overviews = clipped.overviews(1)  # first band

# Print the metadata and overviews
print(metadata)
print(overviews)
>>>
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 3340, 'height': 3342, 'count': 22, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(removed)}
[2, 4, 8]
```

**I saw that there are ways to remove overviews after openin the image, still looking for a ways to save the image without the overviews.**

**Edit 3:**
based on user2856 comments, I have checked the profile:

```
src.profile
>>>
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 3340, 'height': 3342, 'count': 22, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(removed), 'blockxsize': 256, 'blockysize': 256, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'lzw', 'interleave': 'pixel'}

clipped.profile
>>>
{'driver': 'GTiff', 'dtype': 'float32', 'nodata': None, 'width': 3340, 'height': 3342, 'count': 22, 'crs': CRS.from_epsg(4326), 'transform': Affine(removed), 'blockxsize': 512, 'blockysize': 512, 'tiled': True, 'compress': 'lzw', 'interleave': 'pixel'}
```

I have immediately realized that the difference between the clipped image to the original image is that the clipped image has different blocksize (512 instead of 256)
I was trying to force the clipped image to have 256 when I write it.:

```
    with rasterio.open(savedir /tiff_name, 
                                   'w',
                                   driver='cog',
                                   height=img.shape[1],
                                   width=img.shape[2],
                                   count=number_of_bands,
                                   dtype=img.dtype,
                                   crs=crs_img,
                                   nodata=None, # change if data has nodata value,
                                   blockxsize=256, 
                                   blockysize=256,
                                   transform=transf) as dst:

            for n in np.arange(0,number_of_bands):
                  
                  dst.write(img[n,:,:],int(n+1))
                  dst.set_band_description(int(n+1), band_names[n])
```

But when I was checking the size of the forced blocksize, it still was too large (954MB...)  and it seems like blocksize doesn't really change when I print profile

Comment: Compressed images tend to be always smaller than uncompressed images. Notice also that COG by default contains overview levels and they add about 30% to the file size (but with a good reason).

Comment: @user30184 thank you for your comment. If I compress them, what will change in the image? how will it influence the pixels values?

Comment: I just tried your code.  The COG driver writes the output with LZW (lossless) compression by default. Your original image may not have overviews.

Comment: @user2856 so that means that it's not about compression right?

Comment: Depends on whether your version of the COG driver writes with compression. Why don't you check? `rio info savedir/clipped.tif`

Comment: There's no way your question can be answered without info about your input and output rasters.  Suggest you edit your question to include output of either `rio info filename.tif` and `rio overview --ls filename.tif` or `gdalinfo filename.tif` for both the input and output rasters.

Comment: Please clarify what is "GCS".

Comment: @AndreaGiudiceandrea Google cloud storage, sorry for the confusion. Added to the original post as well.

Comment: @user2856 I have added information about overviews

Comment: @Reut `Dataset.meta` is just the basic metadata, to see if it's compressed, use `Dataset.profile` - https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/283134/2856

Comment: @user2856 added this information + something I have tried based on it

Comment: Ok, it's definitely the overviews.  `src.overviews(1) == []` and `clipped.overviews(1) == [2, 4, 8]`.  So my question is... now that you know why, does it matter? I ask, because if you remove the overviews, it's not a valid COG, but just a geotiff. So why wouldn't you just write a geotiff in the first place using `src.profile`  i.e. `rasterio.open(savedir /'clipped.tif', 'w', **src.profile) as dst:`

Comment: @user2856 for your question - I have tried also to save it as gtiff, it's still very large - less than a cog but it's 936MB.  The idea to write as cog is mainly for using it on GEE (cogs are required) . I have added also an attempt to reduce the blockxsize which also seems to have difference (edited the post).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As user2856 thought, I was able to get reasonable file size by defining overviews=None when writing the result clipped image using rasterio.
It was something like this:

```
#img is ndarray
with rasterio.open(savedir /tiff_name, 
                                   'w',
                                   driver='cog',
                                   height=img.shape[1],
                                   width=img.shape[2],
                                   count=15,
                                   dtype=img.dtype,
                                   crs=crs_img,
                                   nodata=None, 
                                   
                               #this is what I added - overviews
                                   overviews=None,
                                   transform=transf) as dst:

            for n in np.arange(0,15):
                  
                  dst.write(img[n,:,:],n+1)
```